# Java SSL connection reset on Linux, Windows works fine

Tags: java, .net, ssl, apache-camel

We're trying to connect to a .NET-based webservice with Apache Camel over HTTPS. The calls run fine under Windows, but Linux-based machines are served a connection reset by the remote webservice during the SSL handshake phase. Calling the URL's from cURL or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) under Linux is no problem, so the problem seems related to the JVM.

We've tested this with SSL trace logging enabled and both machines seem to negotiate exactly the same cipher suite and such, so we're clueless as to why the connection is being reset. We haven't got access to the logging of the remote webservice's logging so I'm actually not sure how to continue debugging this issue...

I've truncated the SSL trace logging for both platforms and included it below. Is there anything we've missed in there, or is there any more we can do to debug this issue without the remote logging?

Linux SSL trace logging:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1509952410 bytes = ...truncated...
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=...truncated...]
***
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 230
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 91
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 720603056 bytes = ...truncated...
Session ID:  ...truncated...
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3959
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: ...truncated...
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
...truncated...


[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsextendvalsha2g3r3.crt
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsextendvalsha2g3r3
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsextendvalsha2g3r3.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: ...truncated...
  qualifier: ...truncated...

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ...truncated...
  DNSName: ...truncated...
  DNSName: ...truncated...
]

[10]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/rootr3
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

[4]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.com/root-r3.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: ...truncated...
  qualifier: ...truncated...

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[7]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...

]
chain [2] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
...truncated...
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
...truncated...
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature: ...truncated...

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: ...truncated...
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:...truncated...
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...
]
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: ...truncated...
  public y coord: ...truncated...
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  ...truncated...
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
...truncated...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
...truncated...
Server Nonce:
...truncated...
Master Secret:
...truncated...
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
...truncated...
Server write key:
...truncated
Client write IV:
...truncated...
Server write IV:
...truncated....
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
...truncated...
***
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
http-nio-8080-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
*** Finished
...truncated...
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 2370
http-nio-8080-exec-7, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
http-nio-8080-exec-7, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8080-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
http-nio-8080-exec-7, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
http-nio-8080-exec-7, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-7, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-7, called closeInternal(true)
```

Windows SSL trace logging:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1509957147 bytes = ...truncated...
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=...truncated...]
***
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 258
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 91
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -607016418 bytes = ...truncated...
Session ID:  ...truncated...
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 3959
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: ...truncated...
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
...truncated...


[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsextendvalsha2g3r3.crt
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsextendvalsha2g3r3
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[5]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsextendvalsha2g3r3.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: ...truncated...
  qualifier: ...truncated...

]]  ]
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[]  ]
]

[7]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ...truncated...
  DNSName: ...truncated...
  DNSName: ...truncated...
]

[10]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G3, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 7
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/rootr3
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:0
]

[4]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl.globalsign.com/root-r3.crl]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [...truncated...]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: ...truncated...
  qualifier: ...truncated...

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[7]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...

]
chain [2] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated...

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
...truncated...
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
...truncated...
]

[3]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature: ...truncated...

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = ...truncated

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: ...truncated...
  public exponent: ...truncated...
  Validity: [...truncated...]
  Issuer: ...truncated...
  SerialNumber: [    ...truncated...]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:...truncated...
]

[2]: ObjectId: ...truncated... Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
...truncated...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
...truncated...
]
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 333
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: ...truncated...
  public y coord: ...truncated...
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 144, 81, 42, 27, 249, 12, 198, 167, 196, 189, 75, 11, 160, 39, 39, 10, 147, 244, 224, 161, 27, 200, 75, 153, 157, 161, 124, 97, 202, 134, 160, 96, 188, 86, 81, 42, 150, 115, 66, 254, 51, 50, 149, 2, 63, 191, 181, 70, 178, 233, 233, 207, 214, 235, 200, 52, 51, 47, 139, 211, 246, 147, 2, 250 }
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
...truncated...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
...truncated...
Server Nonce:
...truncated...
Master Secret:
...truncated...
0020: 5B 12 25 BC 53 8B 7C B8   D3 35 60 56 EE D8 8C E4  [.%.S....5`V....
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
...truncated...
Server write key:
...truncated...
Client write IV:
...truncated...
Server write IV:
...truncated...
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data: ...truncated...
***
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
*** Finished
verify_data: ...truncated...
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 2348
http-nio-8080-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 1123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've actually found the issue with help from the remote logging: on the Linux-machine, the URL that was requested included a port number (i.e. `https://remote:443`) whereas the Windows-machine the URL was defined without the port (i.e. `https://remote`). After removing the port from the Linux-configuration, everything runs fine.

AFAIK the port number should not be part of certificate validation, but the remote webservice seems to include it anyways. Anyhow, our problem is solved.